# Building Python3 build system to run the py file in MacOS terminal

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

I have built a python3 system in ST3 using the following codes.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python3 -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        },

            "name": "Run in cmd",
            "shell_cmd": "start cmd /c \"python3 ${file} & pause\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I choose "Build with" and run "Run in cmd", the error occurred:

[screen shot of command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtViN.png)

May I know how I could modify the build system such that I can run the py file in terminal?

Comment: Maybe try removing `start cmd /c` since it's not a valid `bash` command.

Comment: But it shows /bin/bash: python3 /Users/admin/Desktop/untitled.py: No such file or directory

Comment: Try it like this: `"shell_cmd": "python3 \"${file}\""`, or perhaps `"shell_cmd": "./Users/admin/Desktop/untitled.py"`; pay attention to the quotes.

Comment: Not working.  Wonder if there is any problem with my ST. :(